# How to Import Coq library HoTT in CoqIde

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, formal-verification, formal-methods, coqide

I want to use HoTT library in my CoqIde. My environment is `Coq_Platform_2021.09.0.8.13-installer-windows-x86_64-signed` and I have tried a lot of methods.

1. I tried to write `Require Import HoTT.` in CoqIde and get the error `Unable to locate library HoTT. (While searching for a .vos file.)`
2. I tried to write `From HoTT Require Import Basics.` or `Require Import HoTT.Basics.` and I get the error `Notation "~ _" is already defined at level 75 with arguments constr at level 75`
3. However, I can load some libraries such as `UnivalenceAxiom` by writing `From HoTT Require Import UnivalenceAxiom.` 
   So my question is how to import HoTT library in my CoqIde?

Comment: With solution 2, are you sure what you get is an error and not just a warning?

Comment: Yes, it is an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put a file named _CoqProject with the following contents:

```
-arg -noinit
-arg -indices-matter
```

In your project root folder (from which you load the file using HoTT).

It would help if you could tell us the places where you looked for documentation on this, so that we can adjust it. It is e.g. documented in opam (say if you do `opam show coq-hott`), but I guess this is not the most obvious place to look fot his.

Comment: So do I need to compile the Coq file using _CoqProject? I have put this file in my project root folder but still can't load the HoTT library.

Comment: No, just put the file there, and possibly start CoqIDE from this folder.

Alternatively you can also start CoqIDE with `coqide -noinit -indices-matter`.

Comment: Did the _CoqProject method work for you, or only the command line version?

Comment: From the command line and I write ```From HoTT Require Import HoTT.```

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue and "fixed" it by adding this line to the top of my file, before importing HoTT: `Reserved Notation "~ x" (at level 35, right associativity).`

So my entire file looked like:

```
Reserved Notation "~ x" (at level 35, right associativity).
From HoTT Require Import HoTT.
```

And it worked fine from there on. Confusingly, Emacs highlighted the notation line as an error, yet it loads fine and I can continue onwards. IMO this seems like a bug with more recent versions of Coq.