# Importing HoTT library in Coq

Tags: coq, homotopy-type-theory

I'm trying to use `coq-hott` library in Coq, but the import won't work. I'm working in the container of the `coqorg/coq:latest` docker image. After starting the container I've done the following:

0. `opam install coq-hott` in the container's terminal.
1. Hooked up `vscode` to the container and installed the VsCoq extension there.
2. Set the paths to `_CoqProject` and `coqtop`.
3. Created the `_CoqProject` file with the following lines:

```
    -arg -noinit
    -arg -indices-matter
```

4. Checked the HoTT library location: `/home/coq/.opam/4.05.0/lib/coq/user-contrib/HoTT`

After creating the `*.v` file to test the library I got the following problems:

0. `Require Import HoTT.` gives

```
Cannot find a physical path bound to logical path HoTT.
```

1. `From HoTT Require Import Basics.` works, but doing `Check (2+2).` after that gives

```
The term "2" has type "trunc_index" while it is expected to have type "Type".
```

2. `From HoTT Require Import Algebra.` works but `From HoTT Require Import Analysis.` gives

```
Cannot find a physical path bound to logical path Analysis with prefix HoTT.
```

I don't understand this behavior at all. It is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70283920/how-to-import-coq-library-hott-in-coqide), but still different. Am I doing something wrong ?

According to `opam` the packages versions for `coq` and `coq-hott` are `8.15.1 [4.07.1+flambda 4.05.0]` and `8.15 [4.05.0]` respectively.